# How to fix this error in ionic 3

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

**Error:**

> UP-TO-DATE :app:splitsDiscoveryTaskDebug UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:processDebugResources
>   D:\ion\eventmanagement\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\manifests\full\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:106:
>   AAPT: error: resource string/fb_app_id (aka
>   io.ionic.starter:string/fb_app_id) not found.
>   D:\ion\eventmanagement\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\manifests\full\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:109:
>   AAPT: error: resource string/fb_app_name (aka
>   io.ionic.starter:string/fb_app_name) not found.
>
> D:\ion\eventmanagement\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\manifests\full\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:113:
>   AAPT: error: resource string/fb_app_name (aka
>   io.ionic.starter:string/fb_app_name) not found.
>
> D:\ion\eventmanagement\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\manifests\full\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:106:
>   error: resource string/fb_app_id (aka
>   io.ionic.starter:string/fb_app_id) not found.
>   D:\ion\eventmanagement\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\manifests\full\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:109:
>   error: resource string/fb_app_name (aka
>   io.ionic.starter:string/fb_app_name) not found.
>   D:\ion\eventmanagement\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\manifests\full\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:113:
>   error: resource string/fb_app_name (aka
>   io.ionic.starter:string/fb_app_name) not found. error: failed
>   processing manifest.
>
> Failed to execute aapt
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute
>   aapt
>           at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.processResources(AndroidBuilder.java:796)
>           at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ProcessAndroidResources.invokeAaptForSplit(ProcessAndroidResources.java:551)
>           at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ProcessAndroidResources.doFullTaskAction(ProcessAndroidResources.java:285)
>           at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask.taskAction(IncrementalTask.java:109)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>           at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:173)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:134)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:121)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:122)
>           at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
>           at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
>           at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
>           at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:111)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:92)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:63)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:88)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
>           at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
>           at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
>           at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
>           at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
>           at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
>           at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
>           at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
>           at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:124)
>           at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:80)
>           at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:105)
>           at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:99)
>           at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:625)
>           at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:580)
>           at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:99)
>           at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
>           at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>           at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for
>   details
>           at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.getDoneValue(AbstractFuture.java:503)
>           at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:482)
>           at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$TrustedFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:79)
>           at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.processResources(AndroidBuilder.java:794)
>           ... 48 more Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for
>   details
>           at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.getDoneValue(AbstractFuture.java:503)
>           at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:462)
>           at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$TrustedFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:79)
>
> ```
>     at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.QueueableAapt2.lambda$makeValidatedPackage$1(QueueableAapt2.java:179)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>     ... 1 more Caused by: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
>     at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess$NotifierProcessOutput.handleOutput(AaptProcess.java:454)
>     at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess$NotifierProcessOutput.err(AaptProcess.java:411)
>     at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess$ProcessOutputFacade.err(AaptProcess.java:332)
>     at com.android.utils.GrabProcessOutput$1.run(GrabProcessOutput.java:104)
> ```
>
> FAILED
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
>
>   > Failed to execute aapt
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED 25 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 24 up-to-date  in 42s
>
> (node:21224) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: cmd: Command
>   failed with exit code 1 Error output:
>   D:\ion\eventmanagement\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\manifests\full\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:106:
>   AAPT: error: resource string/fb_app_id (aka
>   io.ionic.starter:string/fb_app_id) not found.
>   D:\ion\eventmanagement\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\manifests\full\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:109:
>   AAPT: error: resource string/fb_app_name (aka
>   io.ionic.starter:string/fb_app_name) not found.
>
> D:\ion\eventmanagement\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\manifests\full\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:113:
>   AAPT: error: resource string/fb_app_name (aka
>   io.ionic.starter:string/fb_app_name) not found.
>
> D:\ion\eventmanagement\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\manifests\full\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:106:
>   error: resource string/fb_app_id (aka
>   io.ionic.starter:string/fb_app_id) not found.
>   D:\ion\eventmanagement\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\manifests\full\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:109:
>   error: resource string/fb_app_name (aka
>   io.ionic.starter:string/fb_app_name) not found.
>   D:\ion\eventmanagement\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\manifests\full\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:113:
>   error: resource string/fb_app_name (aka
>   io.ionic.starter:string/fb_app_name) not found. error: failed
>   processing manifest.
>
> Failed to execute aapt
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute
>   aapt
>           at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.processResources(AndroidBuilder.java:796)
>           at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ProcessAndroidResources.invokeAaptForSplit(ProcessAndroidResources.java:551)
>           at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ProcessAndroidResources.doFullTaskAction(ProcessAndroidResources.java:285)
>           at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask.taskAction(IncrementalTask.java:109)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>           at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:173)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:134)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:121)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:122)
>           at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
>           at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
>           at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
>           at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:111)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:92)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:63)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:88)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
>           at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
>           at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
>           at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
>           at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
>           at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
>           at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
>           at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
>           at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:124)
>           at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:80)
>           at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:105)
>           at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:99)
>           at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:625)
>           at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:580)
>           at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:99)
>           at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
>           at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>           at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for
>   details
>           at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.getDoneValue(AbstractFuture.java:503)
>           at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:482)
>           at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$TrustedFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:79)
>           at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.processResources(AndroidBuilder.java:794)
>           ... 48 more Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for
>   details
>           at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.getDoneValue(AbstractFuture.java:503)
>           at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:462)
>           at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$TrustedFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:79)
>           at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.QueueableAapt2.lambda$makeValidatedPackage$1(QueueableAapt2.java:179)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>           ... 1 more Caused by: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
>           at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess$NotifierProcessOutput.handleOutput(AaptProcess.java:454)
>           at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess$NotifierProcessOutput.err(AaptProcess.java:411)
>           at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess$ProcessOutputFacade.err(AaptProcess.java:332)
>           at com.android.utils.GrabProcessOutput$1.run(GrabProcessOutput.java:104)
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
>
>   > Failed to execute aapt
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 42s
>       at ChildProcess.whenDone (D:\ion\eventmanagement\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\cordova-common\src\superspawn.js:169:23)
>       at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
>       at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:961:16)
>       at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:248:5) (node:21224)
>   UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This
>   error originated either by throwing inside of an async function
>   without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled
>   with .catch(). (rejection id: 1) (node:21224) [DEP0018]
>   DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In
>   the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the
>   Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Comment: try running command: ionic doctor check , can be a problem with modules. Then remove android platform and add again! Let me know if that works. Regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you install the Facebook plugin you did not provide `APP_ID` and `APP_NAME` like in bellow example. Check the `config.xml` to verify this. More information could be found in their [DOC](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/facebook/).

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-facebook4 --variable APP_ID="123456789" --variable APP_NAME="myApplication"
```

Hope this help to you!

Comment: I will get Same same error for this guy. below the link

Comment: config the app_id & application name in ( ionic.config.json ) file. After run  ionic cordova platform add android@6.3.0 and build your .apk